# Send different email template based on the foreign language

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3, sendgrid

Can anyone suggest the correct way of sending an email template as shown below based on the foreign language?
I get the language from the url, I initially thought to use a switch but I would like to know if there is any other more clean solution.

```
$lang = $this->request->query['language'];
$email->addTo()->
                   setFrom('')->
                   setFromName('')->
                   setSubject(' ')->
                   setHtml(' ')->
                   addSubstitution())->
                   addSubstitution()->
                   addFilter("templates", "enable", 1)->
                   addFilter("templates", "template_id", '32e97d67-72d8-449e-a864-ffd088e72f26'));


            $res = $sendgrid->send($email);
```

Comment: How are you storing your different language templates? I mean you could store each template in a different file and read the file based on the lang var. Or same thing with an array using `$lang` as the key

Comment: This doesn't look like Cake 1.3 nor like you're using the regular CakePHP CakeEmail class...